# Deriving the Heat capacity from Fermi-Dirac statistics

Tags: abstract-algebra, integration

I am putting this question on maths stack exchange after physics as I feel it is more mathematically oriented. I was watching the lectures on Solid state physics by Steve Simon (Oxford). He was explaining how to find Heat capacity of metal due to electrons from Fermi-Dirac statistics. You can write the total number of electrons as $$N =g(E_f) \int_0^\infty \frac{E^\frac{1}{2}}{1+e^{\beta(E-u)}}dE.$$

Here, $g(E_f)$ is the density of states which you can assume to be a known constant and $\beta=\frac{1}{kT}$. Now, from this formula, if you know $N$ and temperature, you should be able to figure out $u$ (chemical potential). Then, you can find average energy by averaging the integral above with $E$ multiplied. From there, you can get specific heat by differentiating with respect to temperature. He didn't do it this way as it involves a lot of algebra according to him. I tried solving the integral but couldn't do it. Can anyone solve it to get the expression for $u$ or provide some reference?

Comment: Can you clarify this sentence: "Then, you can find average energy by averaging the integral above with E multiplied."? How can we find the average energy by averaging the integral above, if the integral above gives $N$?

Comment: @the_candyman To find the expected(average) value of energy in the system, you have to do the same integral as above with E multiplied, i.e, the numerator will now have E^(3/2). Basically, the expression on the right is actually the probability density of an electron occupying state between energy E and E+dE.